# Laravel send email verification to a registered user

Tags: laravel, email-verification

I am new to Laravel. I have easily implemented Laravel email verification for the registered based on Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification

its working fine for testing purpose in local server. now I want to upload to server. now it's using default Mailtrap to receive an email of all the users.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

//user.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
```

My requirement is after registering, the email should send to the registered emailId, not to the mailtrap account. I have researched a lot on this in google but all the solution is only for sending emails to mailtrap or others but instead, I want to send to the users' email ID with the verification link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have successfully implemented the activation email. 
For your application to send email to the registered user email address you need to provide your email server SMTP credentials. For live application, you can not use mail trap credentials. If you use mailtrap credentials you will only get emails to your mail trap account.

If you do not have live smtp server credential, you can create a Gmail account and user Gmail SMTP credentials. 
And one more thing, if you are using Gmail, change settings for `Less secure app` from your google account.

Comment: where I will get my email server SMTP credentials? do you have any idea?

Comment: https://www.wpsitecare.com/gmail-smtp-settings/ check the settings,  then go to you google account and privacy settings then allow ' less secure app'      here for setting less secure app https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/

Comment: I have my own hosting account and I have an email id is created. but my doubt is which MAIL_DRIVER and MAIL_HOST and PORT I should use?

Comment: Then you will have to check ur hosting provider for the smtp credentials and port and host

Comment: sure. I will try

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null    it gives me Connection to smtp.mydomain.com:465 Timed Out error

Comment: Try encription as `tls`

Comment: yes, I resolved it. the issue is not only with encryption but with the port. I changed the port from 465 to 578 but the mail was going to spam folder. Again I changed the port to 25 and it working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

this is .env configuration you have change to your own mail server. so that laravel will send email using these settings to the registered users.